# Compute statistics for a JavaRDD in an optimum way

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I need to do complex computation over a huge RDD ,but for the sake of simplicity i've reduced my problem to something much simpler:

I have a JavaRDD obtained like this:

```
 JavaRDD<Student> students = sc.parallelize(
                javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "school",   mapRowTo(Student.class)).collect());
```

The Student class look like:

```
public class Student implements Serializable{
    Integer id;
    Integer classroom;
    String name;
    Integer mark1;
    Integer mark2;
   // ... getters and setters
```

Now, i want in **one iteration** to have the stddedv, avg for mark1 and mark2 columns for every classrooms using if it's possible StatCounter.
I know how to use StatCounter, but over a

```
JavaRDD<Numeric>
```

and  in my case i have

```
JavaRDD<Student>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, never:

```
sc.parallelize(someRDD.collect());
```

It just cannot be a good idea. Like ever.

Now:

> one iteration to have the stddedv, avg for mark1 and mark2 columns for every classrooms using if it's possible StatCounter

It is possible, but just use `DataFrame` with [Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md):

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

spark
 .read
 .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
 .options(Map( "table" -> "school", "keyspace" -> "test"))
 .load()
 .groupBy("classroom"))
 .agg(mean("mark1"), stddev("mark1"), mean("mark2"), stddev("mark2"));
```

With stat counter you can convert  `JavaPairRDD<Integer,Tuple2<Integer,Integer>>` (`(class, (mark1, , mark2))`) and `combineByKey` with a `Tuple2` of `StatCounters`. You can also replace `Tuple2` with `mllib.Vector` and aggregate with `MultivariateStatisticalSummary`

Comment: So, if you have 3 nodes (for example) with Spark and Cassandra, reading it with parralelize, it will bring data splited from every nodes in the JavaRDD. Even on their video lessons, Datastax use only javaRDD and not DataFrames